# defining functions with/without lambdas

Tags: haskell, lambda, ghc

Which difference in does it make if I define a function with a lambda expression or without so when compiling the module with GHC

```
f :: A -> B
f = \x -> ...
```

vs.

```
f :: A -> B
f x = ...
```

I think I saw that it helps the compiler to inline the function but other than that can it have an impact on my code if I change from the first to the second version.

I am trying to understand someone else's code and get behind the reasoning why this function is defined in the first and not the second way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, the second form is just more flexible (it allows you to do pattern matching, with other clauses below for alternative cases).

When there's only one clause, it's actually equivalent to a lambda... unless you have a `where` scope. Namely,

```
f = \x -> someCalculation x y
 where y = expensiveConstCalculation
```

is more efficient than

```
f x = someCalculation x y
 where y = expensiveConstCalculation
```

because in the latter, `y` is always recalculated when you evaluate `f` with a different argument. In the lambda form, `y` is re-used:

- If the signature of `f` is monomorphic, then `f` is a [constant applicative form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form), i.e. global constant. That means `y` is shared throughout your entire program, and only `someCalculation` needs to be re-done for each call of `f`. This is typically ideal performance-wise, though of course it also means that `y` keeps occupying memory.
- If `f` s polymorphic, then it is in fact implicitly a function of the types you're using it with. That means you don't get global sharing, but if you write e.g. `map f longList`, then still `y` needs to be computed only once before getting mapped over the list.

That's the gist of the performance differences. Now, of course GHC can rearrange stuff and since it's guaranteed that the results are the same, it might always transform one form to the other if deemed more efficient. But normally it doesn't.

Comment: does this reasoning of `y` being shared also apply to `let`-bindings or is there a difference when `where`-clauses are used?

Comment: Won't the full laziness transformation take care of that efficiency concern?

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure there can be a difference in how GHC treats the function for inlining-function applications are inclined only when "fully applied". Inlining too early can be a problem sometimes, I gather, which is why some list functions are written with extra arguments. Or something like that.

Answer (score 8):

To answer that question, I wrote a little program with both ways, and looked at the Core generated:

```
f1 :: Int -> Int
f1 = \x -> x + 2
{-# NOINLINE f1 #-}

f2 :: Int -> Int
f2 x = x + 2
{-# NOINLINE f2 #-}
```

I get the core by running `ghc test.hs -ddump-simpl`. The relevant part is:

```
f1_rjG :: Int -> Int
[GblId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType]
f1_rjG =
  \ (x_alH :: Int) -> + @ Int GHC.Num.$fNumInt x_alH (GHC.Types.I# 2)

f2_rlx :: Int -> Int
[GblId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType]
f2_rlx =
  \ (x_amG :: Int) -> + @ Int GHC.Num.$fNumInt x_amG (GHC.Types.I# 2)
```

The results are identical, so to answer your question: there is no impact from changing from one form to the other.

---

That being said, I recommend looking at leftaroundabout's answer, which deals about the cases where there actually is a difference.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating how to actually check what GHC produces, however  it's not true that both forms are identical under all circumstances.